# Webdriver Test Stalls When Twitter Login Window Pops Up

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to run a simple test that navigates to a site & attempts to register with the site using twitter.  For some reason the test just stalls when I click on the twitter button and the login window pops up.  I have been unable to find anything (at least up until now) while searching google, the selenium usergroup, or stackoverflow.  I am wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar problem or if I am missing something profoundly simple.  Thanks in advance.  Code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re

class TwReg(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "sitename"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def test_tw_reg(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("tw_one_click_btn").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

To make sure I am clearly articulating what is going on.  The above code should quit after the twitter sing in window pops up, instead it simply hangs at that point.  This code is generated by Selenium's IDE.  Thanks again.

Comment: Quick update: I tried this with ChromeDriver as well and encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know python at all but it looks as though your code isn't telling the webdriver to switch to the popup window. After the webdriver clicks the button, it is trying to find the element "what" on the login page rather than in the popup. Because the login window no longer has focus it doesn't fire the NoSuchElementException but rather times out. So you need to add a line to the code to switch to the popup window after it opens.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did not realize that this question was still open.  That was definitely one of the issues & I added a couple lines of code that had webdriver switch focus to the pop-up.  Another confounding issue at the time was Twitters auth wasn't working properly.  Thanks again for answering such an old question.

Comment: No problem - I actually hadn't noticed how old it was! I guess all the new Selenium questions are on the SQA site now. I appreciate you accepting the answer.